# twig access file1 block in file3 via file2 include

Tags: twig

Twig template file1 is included in file2 and the template file2 is extended in file3 can i access the template file1 block in the template file 3

file1

```
{% block testBlock %} file1 {% endblock %}
```

file2

```
<div>
{% include '/testfolder/insidefolder/file1.tpl' %}
</div>
```

file3

```
{% extends "file2.tpl" %}   

{% block testBlock %}
  overridden block
{% endblock %}
```

it does not override the file1 template testBlock in the file3

Comment: In file3, did you mean `{% block testBlock %}` instead of `{% block passengerDetails %}`?

Comment: sorry typo error... it remains same as testBlock

Comment: File3 can't adjust the blocks in File 2 or File 1